# IIS First Start is too slow

Tags: .net, iis

I have an application that takes about 20 or 30 minutes to run completely after the IIS restart. While that it happens the pages are very slow and many timeouts are displayed.

Can anyone help me to diagnose this?

Aplication Server: IIS 7,5

System: Window 2008 r2 sp1

CPUs: 8

RAM: 16gb

Application DLLs quantity: 2083

.NET version: 3,5

Comment: Maybe it's your application that is doing some initialization for 20-30 minutes?

Comment: I have the same problem, How did you solve this problem. @TiagoRocha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I've needed to eliminate about 1000 dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Read the timeout messages. See if that tells you where the slowdown is.
2. Set some breakpoints in the code. You can use them to narrow down the slow place or places.